# After certain week of 2022 and continue with this new year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to request some advice about how to set a Where Condition, but after a certain week

What I mean is:

I have dirty data before a specific week of 2022, so I made this:

```
DATEPART(WK, SA.FECHAE) >= 44
AND 
YEAR(SA.FECHAE) >= 2022
```

But, We're on 2023, so, I need to add the new information of this new year year too into the query.

The query result shows me until 12-31-2022 and need it until today after the week 44 of 2022

Comment: Why not replace the logic you have with the actual start date of that week? `WHERE SA.FECHAE >= {Start date of Week 44 in 2022} AND SA.FECHAE < GETDATE()`?

Comment: Your query returns rows where the week number is equal to or greater than `44` *and* the year is greater than or equal to `2022`, so week `45` of `2023` would meet that requirement (`45` is greater than `44` and `2023` is greater than `2022`), however, week `1` of `2023` would not (as `1` is less than `44`). The query you have is also non-SARGable, so is ill advised anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
 WHERE (
            DATEPART(WEEK, SA.FECHAE) >= 44
        AND YEAR(SA.FECHAE) = 2022
       ) 
    OR (
            YEAR(SA.FECHAE) >= 2023
       )
```

In the OPs question they ask how to add an additional date range to their WHERE clause. The addition of this OR allows a second date range (in this case anything where the year is greater than or equal to 2023) to match the predicate and be returned, without impacting the original.

Plain English definition of the amended where clause:
Week 44 of 2022, or any week of any year from 2023 forward.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This is a pretty straight forward amendment to the OPs existing code. I thought it was self evident, as it just adds an OR to the predicate.
However, I can add explicit clarification as to what is added, and why it would resolve the OPs question.